# (Temporarily) disabling deprecation warnings in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm currently developing a large project using Symfony and Sonata-Admin.
I'm adding more and more attention to the deprecation warnings triggered by various components of the code.

But while looking at over 400 deprecation warnings, I can't find a spot to start with, so I want to temporarly disable deprecation notes from some of the third-party libraries to identify mine and selected third-party libraries (e.g. Sonata-Admin).

Is there a way to disable deprecation warnings in parts of my project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way to do it would probably be a pain to work with. You can disable the warnings by default and turn on error reporting in the top your scripts using [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting). Then just reset back to previous value at the end of your script. There is nothing automated that will do this for you by changing the error reporting based on the script included.

Comment: Sounds like pain, yes. But it could be automate-able by using sed or similar. Worth a try, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED &amp; ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: And how exactly would that disable the notices from some bundles but not others?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since I do not want to disable error reporting at all. Just want to focus while working on my project.